# Do the algebras for a $\infty$-monad form a stable $\infty$-category?

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

I'm wondering if a [monad](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%28infinity%2C1%29-monad) $T$ on a stable $\infty$-category $\cal C$ has a stable $\infty$-category of algebras, provided $T$ preserves finite limits/colimits.

Is this true?

**Edit**: Is something similar true in the triangulated world?

Comment: Not super confident but I'll say yes: we have a monadic (because $T$ is a monad) free-forget adjunction $Alg_{T}(\mathcal{C}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ so that $Alg_T(\mathcal{C})$ is equivalent to its essential image in $\mathcal{C}$. This means that limits and colimits are computed in $\mathcal{C}$ so that limits diagrams are indeed colimit diagrams, hence stable.

Comment: Alg_T(C) is certainly *not* equivalent to its image in C! The maps are not the same.

Comment: On the other hand, maybe the OPs assumptions on $T$ will force the forgetful functor to preserve finite coproducts... since the forgetful functor preserves sifted colimits, this should give you the preservation of colimits that you're after. (If it works it will probably work under the weaker assumption that $T$ preserves coproducts.)

Comment: Yes, I believe the (rather strong, indeed) fact that any shape of colimits preserved by T is preserved by the forgetful exports to the infty-setting. I didn't work out all details yet, but I believe (not 100% sure) the claim is true.

Comment: Since I believe the claim is true (at least in the generality I need), I added a new question to the OP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The statement about stable $\infty$-categories is true. Just as in ordinary categories the basic facts about limits and colimits in the category of algebras are that the forgetful functor $\mathrm{Alg}(T) \to \mathcal{C}$

1. creates any limits that $\mathcal{C}$ admits, without any assumption on $T$, and
2. creates colimits of any shape $X$ such that $\mathcal{C}$ admits $X$-shaped colimits and the underlying functor of $T$ preserves them.

These are Theorem 5.7 and Corollary 5.5 in Emily Riehl and Dominic Verity's paper [Completeness results for quasi-categories of algebras, homotopy limits, and related general constructions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6247).

If $\mathcal{C}$ is stable and the underlying functor of $T$ is exact, 1 and 2 tell you that a pushout square of algebras is a pushout square in $\mathcal{C}$ is a pullback square in $\mathcal{C}$ is a pullback square of algebras; so the $\infty$-category of algebras of $T$ is also stable.

EDIT: About triangulated categories I don't know, but take a look at Paul Balmer's [Separability and triangulated categories](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~balmer/research/Pubfile/Sep-Triang.pdf), which seems to contain a similar result for something called separable monads.